# Attempting to load AssetReference that has already been loaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I start the main scene and test a new character it shows this error why?

```
Attempting to load AssetReference that has already been loaded. Handle is exposed through getter OperationHandle
UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.AssetReference:LoadAssetAsync<UnityEngine.GameObject> ()
TrackManager/<SpawnFromAssetReference>d__104:MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Tracks/TrackManager.cs:565)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine (System.Collections.IEnumerator)
TrackManager:SpawnObstacle (TrackSegment) (at Assets/Scripts/Tracks/TrackManager.cs:556)
TrackManager/<SpawnNewSegment>d__102:MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Tracks/TrackManager.cs:538)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)
```

my code :

```
    if (m_SafeSegementLeft <= 0)
    {
        SpawnObstacle(newSegment);
    }
    else
        m_SafeSegementLeft -= 1;

    m_Segments.Add(newSegment);

    if (newSegmentCreated != null) newSegmentCreated.Invoke(newSegment);
}


public void SpawnObstacle(TrackSegment segment)
{
    if (segment.possibleObstacles.Length != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < segment.obstaclePositions.Length; ++i)
        {
            AssetReference assetRef = segment.possibleObstacles[Random.Range(0, segment.possibleObstacles.Length)];
            StartCoroutine(SpawnFromAssetReference(assetRef, segment, i));
        }
    }

    StartCoroutine(SpawnCoinAndPowerup(segment));
}

private IEnumerator SpawnFromAssetReference(AssetReference reference, TrackSegment segment, int posIndex)
{
    AsyncOperationHandle op = reference.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>();
    yield return op; 
    GameObject obj = op.Result as GameObject;
    if (obj != null)
    {
        Obstacle obstacle = obj.GetComponent<Obstacle>();
        if (obstacle != null)
            yield return obstacle.Spawn(segment, segment.obstaclePositions[posIndex]);
    }
}
```

It says i have error in line 565 which is `AsyncOperationHandle op = reference.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>();`

What is the error here?

Comment: Well you pick random `AssetReference`s from a list of `segment.possibleObstacles` ... it is not unlikely that you get the same element twice => you try to load it again ... I would keep a list of already loaded references and skip the loading if the currently selected reference already was loaded before!

Comment: also in general please use the correct tags! [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor like language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now, your code is clearly `c#`. Also [`unity-conainer`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity-container/info) has absolutely nothing to do with the Unity3d GameEngine you are using ....

Answer (score 4):

A little bit late, but after some dig up I found the explaination from Unity_Bill:

> AssetReference.LoadAssetAsync() is a helper we've provided that you in
> no way need to use when loading an AssetReference.
> Addressables.LoadAssetAsync(AssetReference) will work just as well. If
> you do the latter, the async operation handle is returned to you and
> you are in charge of it. You can call that as many times as you want,
> and get as many handles as you want. Each will be ref-counted.
>
> If you choose to use the AssetReference.LoadAssetAsync() helper, the
> asset reference itself will hold on to the handle. This enabled the
> helper method AssetReference.ReleaseAsset(). Prior to 1.15.1, if you
> called load twice, the first handle would simply get stomped. If you
> happened to keep up with it, great, but if not, it was lost forever.
>
> So, in short, AssetReference.LoadAssetAsync() is a convenience helper
> that really only works in the most simple case. If you are doing
> anything beyond the simple, and are keeping up with the handles
> yourself, just use Addr.Load... If I were starting addressables over I
> likely wouldn't have the helpers at all, requiring the
> Addressables.Load..(AssetRef) be used instead.

TLDR: Use Addressables.LoadAssetAsync(AssetReference) instead of AssetReference.LoadAssetAsync

You can read more here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/1-15-1-assetreference-not-allow-loadassetasync-twice.959910/

Answer (score 2):

The error message sounds quite self-explanatory: You try to load the same addressable twice.

As said in

```
AssetReference assetRef = segment.possibleObstacles[Random.Range(0, segment.possibleObstacles.Length)];
```

you pick a random entry from available addressables. However, nothing here prevents that you get casually the same element twice.

I would rather either keep track of which ones already are loaded

```
Dictionary<AssetReference, GameObject> loadedAssets = new Dictionary<AssetReference, GameObject>();
```

and then do

```
private IEnumerator SpawnFromAssetReference(AssetReference reference, TrackSegment segment, int posIndex)
{
    if(!loadedAssets.TryGetValue(reference, out var obj || !obj)
    {
        loadedAssets.Add(reference, null);
        AsyncOperationHandle op = reference.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>();
        yield return op; 
        obj = op.Result;

        loadedAssets[reference] = obj;
    }
    
    if(!obj.TryGetComponent<Obstacle>(out var obstacle))
    {
        Debug.LogError($"No {nameof(Obstacle)} component on loaded object!");
        yield break;
    }
    
    yield return obstacle.Spawn(segment, segment.obstaclePositions[posIndex]);
}
```

And then of course whenever you `Release` one of the loaded assets you also want to

```
loadedAssets.Remove(reference);
```

Or depending on your use case and needs load them all and then start your app if you are going to spawn them more often anyway.

Comment: This approach works perfectly for preloading objects, or for loading 1 object and then having time to load the next one, but if you need to load let's say 5 or 6 it will still attempt to load a address that already exists before it gets added to the list, so far addressables seems to be a bad choice for quick instantiations unless you use LoadAssetAsync().WaitForCompletion(), which in my case makes the game very laggy on console

Comment: You could of course already "pre-add" it to the dictionary when you start loading with a `null` value and fill the value in after the loading is done

Comment: I ended up applying your approach but saving the task in the dictionary as opposed to the task result, so I can check if the result is loaded or not at any time and decide what to do, in my game I do need to instantiate and return whatever is instantiate quite often and changing that now would be a headache after 4 years of development, I feel like the whole addressable approach is still in beta

Answer (score 0):

Following derHugo approach of storing values I came up with this to always have the addressable result ready to be returned as a gameobject but prevent it to be loaded more than once, addressables also has a 'address.LoadAssetAsync().WaitForCompletion()' method but in my case when loading many things it gets too laggy.

```
    private async Task<T> GetNewInstance<T>(AssetReferenceGameObject address) where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        if (!loadedAssetsTask.ContainsKey(address))
        {
            LoadNewAddress<T>(address);
        }

        var asset = await loadedAssetsTask[address];
        var newGameObject = Instantiate(asset);
        var component = newGameObject.GetComponent<T>();

        return component;
    }

    private void LoadNewAddress<T>(AssetReferenceGameObject address) where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        var loadedAssetTask = address.LoadAssetAsync().Task;
        loadedAssetsTask.Add(address, loadedAssetTask);
    }
```